# Are there any violin exercises for advanced playing like Hanon and Brhams for piano?

Tags: violin, exercises

Are there any violin exercises for advanced playing like Hanon and Brhams studies for piano? In other words, what to play except the music itself to develop a better technique in the shortest time possible? Any ideas and experiences in teaching and learning?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are very many instruction and technique books available. Many Etude books are also available, providing technique work using specifically written pieces, which tends to be more entertaining than working repetitive passages.

The list is probably far too long to present as an answer on this site. You can find discussion about the various techniques on sites like violinist.com

Personally, some of the books I use, as an example for you, in no particular order and just from what I remember:

- Sevcik, Otakar -  School of Violin Technics
  (the Sevcik series is a large series of many technique books)
- Schradieck -  School of Violin Technique (excellent finger articulation work)
- Kreutzer - 42 Studies or Caprices
- Galamian - Contemporary Violin Technique
- Wohlfahrt, Franz - 60 Etudes Op. 45

Comment: And while much of Ševčík's stuff is dull (and I mean mindnumbing, excruciating, crawl-up-the-walls dull) it is very focused and thus extremely helpful! Apart from Kreutzer I also used to practice Mazas' etudes, as a more "musical" alternative...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for Études of which there  are many.

You can search for

- Wolfardt
- Sevcik
- Schradieck
- Kreutzer

I’ve used etudes from all of these authors in my violin journey. That list is in order of approximate difficulty.

There are certainly others. These are just what I used and they are mostly in the public domain.